# How can I generate a mysql table of unique random numbers?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a mysql table that has 1000 rows. In each row I'd like to have a random number that is 8 digits in length. In addition, these numbers should be unique.

So basically I need to write something that:

- Creates a random number that is 8 digits in length
- Checks to see if that number has already been added to the table
- If it hasn't already been added, add it now
- Repeat this process until 1000 rows have been created.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 1) write code 2) run code 3) debug code 4) goto #2 until #3 isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Can *all* of the first 7 digits be 0?